# ASP Chart Control - issue displaying all SQL data

Tags: asp.net, mschart

I am new at using MSChart control. I know how to get a single Series of data to display in a column chart, but am having issues with displaying multiple data values in the chart. Here is the data from a SQL query I need to display:

```
Area      TotalCnt   Compliant  CPercent     NonCompliant   NCPercent
Area1      29027      25468      87.7            3559        12.3
Area2      13659      12035      88.1            1624        11.9
Area3      25358      22221      87.6            3137        12.4
Area4      47747      42340      88.7            5407        11.3
```

Here's the Series section of my column chart:

```
<series>
<asp:series IsValueShownAsLabel="true" ChartArea="ChartArea1" Label="#VALY" Name="Compliant" BorderColor="180, 26, 59, 105" Color="#00CC00" XValueMember="Area" YValueMembers="Compliant"></asp:series>
<asp:series IsValueShownAsLabel="true" ChartArea="ChartArea1" Label="#VALY" Name="Non-Compliant" BorderColor="180, 26, 59, 105" Color="255, 0, 0" XValueMember="Area" YValueMembers="NonCompliant"></asp:series>
</series>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Added the entire Chart Control below:

```
<asp:chart id="Chart1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Width="800px" Height="400px" Palette="BrightPastel" BorderColor="181, 64, 1" BorderlineDashStyle="Solid" BackGradientStyle="TopBottom" BorderWidth="2" backcolor="#F3DFC1" imagetype="Png" ImageLocation="~\TempImages\ChartPic_#SEQ(300,3)">
   <titles>
   <asp:title ShadowColor="32, 0, 0, 0" Font="Trebuchet MS, 14.25pt, style=Bold" ShadowOffset="3" Text="DataSource Data Binding" Alignment="TopLeft" ForeColor="26, 59, 105"></asp:title>
   </titles>
    <legends>
        <asp:legend Name="Legend1" Enabled="True" IsTextAutoFit="True" BackColor="Transparent" Font="Trebuchet MS, 8.25pt, style=Bold">
        </asp:legend>
        <asp:Legend HeaderSeparator="Line" Name="Legend2">
                <CellColumns>
                    <asp:LegendCellColumn ColumnType="SeriesSymbol" HeaderText="Region" Name="Column1">
                        <Margins Left="15" Right="15" />
                    </asp:LegendCellColumn>
                </CellColumns>
            </asp:Legend>

    </legends>
    <borderskin skinstyle="Emboss"></borderskin>
        <series>
            <asp:series IsValueShownAsLabel="true" Legend="Legend1" ChartArea="ChartArea1" Label="#VALY" Name="Compliant" BorderColor="180, 26, 59, 105" Color="#00CC00" XValueMember="Area" YValueMembers="Compliant">
            </asp:series>
    <asp:series IsValueShownAsLabel="true" Legend="Legend1" ChartArea="ChartArea1" Label="#VALY" Name="Non-Compliant" BorderColor="180, 26, 59, 105" Color="255, 0, 0" XValueMember="Area" YValueMembers="NonCompliant">
             </asp:series>
        </series>
    <chartareas>
        <asp:chartarea Name="ChartArea1" BorderColor="64, 64, 64, 64" BorderDashStyle="Solid" BackSecondaryColor="White" BackColor="OldLace" ShadowColor="Transparent" BackGradientStyle="TopBottom">
        <area3dstyle Rotation="10" perspective="10" Inclination="15" IsRightAngleAxes="False" wallwidth="0" IsClustered="False"></area3dstyle>              
        <axisx linecolor="64, 64, 64, 64" IsLabelAutoFit="False">
        <labelstyle font="Trebuchet MS, 8.25pt, style=Bold" />
        <LabelStyle Enabled="true" />
        <MajorGrid LineWidth="1" />
        <MajorTickMark Enabled="false" />
        </axisx>
        <axisy linecolor="64, 64, 64, 64" IsLabelAutoFit="False">
        <labelstyle font="Trebuchet MS, 8.25pt, style=Bold" />
        <majorgrid linecolor="64, 64, 64, 64" />
        <LabelStyle Enabled="true" />
        <MajorGrid LineWidth="1" />
        <MajorTickMark Enabled="false" />
        </axisy>
    </asp:chartarea>
  </chartareas>
</asp:chart>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far  (Code Behind) and did you download the MSChart sample web App, I suggest you do if you didn't here http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=14422

Comment: No code behind so far, only using DataSourceID in asp:chart properties.

Comment: I need to show the Percentages with the Totals on each column, or at least in a legend.

Comment: Can you provide the full aspx then, with the Cart control not just the series

Comment: Appended the full asp:chart control code above.